# ¿Cómo hacer una función de un Frame (Cuadro) Para un Menú en C++?

Tags: c++

¿Cómo están? Hago este post porque necesito una ayuda con un mini proyecto que lleva tiempo atormentando mi cabeza (Estoy comenzando a programar). Básicamente es un proyecto simple de un menú que en este caso es una calculadora, pero necesita que tenga un cuadro alrededor (Un frame) en cada uno de los submenus. A continuación les dejaré imágenes y el código del proyecto. Necesito crear una función que me permita hacer que el frame se vea en todos los menús

Acá unas imágenes de lo que quiero arreglar: Como podrán ver, siempre antes de que aparezca cada menú, sale el Frame (Solo) y tengo que presionar cualquier tecla para que se muestre el frame junto con cada uno de los menús de forma correcta. Quisiera solucionar eso.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por último, acá les adjunto el código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void gotoxy(int x, int y){ // MEDIDA de ANCHO = 80, Alto = 25;
    HANDLE hcon = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    COORD dwPos;
    dwPos.X = x;
    dwPos.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hcon, dwPos);
}

void frame(){

    // ESQUINAS //
    gotoxy(0,0);
    cout<<"*";
    gotoxy(0,24);
    cout<<"*";
    gotoxy(79,0);
    cout<<"*";
    gotoxy(79,24);
    cout<<"*";

    // A a B //
    for(int i=1;i<79;i++){
        gotoxy(i,0);
        cout<<"-";
    }
    for(int i=1;i<79;i++){
        gotoxy(i,3);
        cout<<"-";
    }
    // TITULO //
    gotoxy(2,2);
    cout<<"UPTAMCA";

    // B a D //
        for(int l=1;l<24;l++){
        gotoxy(79,l);
        cout<<"|";
    }
        // C a D //
    for(int j=1;j<79;j++){
        gotoxy(j,24);
        cout<<"-";
    }
    for(int j=1;j<79;j++){
        gotoxy(j,22);
        cout<<"-";
    }
        // A a C //

    for(int k=1;k<24;k++){
        gotoxy(0,k);
        cout<<"|";
    }

    // FOOTER //
        gotoxy(2,23);
        cout<<"Marlon Escalona";

        gotoxy(60,23);
        cout<<"Prof Henrry Spitale";


    /* fecha/hora actual basado en el sistema actual */
time_t now = time(0);

    /* Objeto de una estructura tm con fecha/hora local */
tm * time = localtime(&now);

vector<string> mes;
mes.push_back("01");
mes.push_back("02");
mes.push_back("03");
mes.push_back("04");
mes.push_back("05");
mes.push_back("06");
mes.push_back("07");
mes.push_back("08");
mes.push_back("09");
mes.push_back("10");
mes.push_back("11");
mes.push_back("12");

int year = 1900 + time->tm_year;

    //Formato=DIA, NUMERO de MES del AÑO
    gotoxy(68,1);
    cout << time->tm_mday << "/" << mes[time->tm_mon] << "/" << year << endl;
    // HORA //
    gotoxy(70,2);
    cout << time->tm_hour << ":" << time->tm_min << ":" << time->tm_sec << endl;



    system("pause>nul");
}
void menu_principal();
void menu_suma();
void menu_resta();
void menu_multiplicacion();
void menu_dividir();


int main(){
    menu_principal();
    return 0;
}

void menu_principal(){
    bool repite = true;
    int opcion;

    do{
        system("cls");
        frame();        
        // El titulo
        gotoxy(30,1);
        cout<< "MENU PRINCIPAL";
        //Opciones
        gotoxy(5,6);
        cout<<"1. Sumar";
        gotoxy(5,7);
        cout<<"2. Restar";
        gotoxy(5,8);
        cout<<"3. Multiplicar";
        gotoxy(5,9);
        cout<<"4. Dividir";
        gotoxy(5,10);
        cout<<"5. Salir";

        //Leer la respuesta
            gotoxy(5,12);
            cout<<"Opcion: ";
            cin >> opcion;

        //Alternativas

        switch(opcion){
            case 1:
                menu_suma();
                break;

            case 2:
                menu_resta();
                break;

            case 3:
                menu_multiplicacion();
                break;

            case 4:
                menu_dividir();
                break;

            case 5:
                repite = false;
                break;
        }


    }while (repite);
}

void  menu_suma(){

    bool repite = true;
    int opcion;
    int a, b;
    float c, d;

    do{
        system("cls");
        frame();
        // El titulo
        gotoxy(30,1);
        cout<<"MENU SUMA";
        //Opciones
        gotoxy(5,6);
        cout<<"1. Sumar enteros";
        gotoxy(5,7);
        cout<<"2. Sumar flotantes";
        gotoxy(5,8);
        cout<<"3. Regresar";

        //Leer la respuesta
            gotoxy(5,10);
            cout<<"Opcion: ";
            cin >> opcion;
            cout<<"\n";

        //Alternativas
        system("cls");
        frame();
        switch(opcion){
            case 1:

                gotoxy(30,1);
                cout<<"MENU SUMA";
                gotoxy(5,6);
                cout<<"numero 1: ";
                cin >> a;
                gotoxy(5,7);
                cout<<"numero 2: ";
                cin >> b;
                gotoxy(5,9);
                cout << a << " + " << b << " = " << a + b << endl;
                system("pause>nul");
                break;

            case 2:

                gotoxy(30,1);
                cout<<"MENU SUMA\n";
                gotoxy(5,6);
                cout<<"numero 1: ";
                cin >> c;
                gotoxy(5,7);
                cout<<"numero 2: ";
                cin >> d;
                gotoxy(5,9);
                cout << c <<" + " << d <<" = " <<c + d << endl;
                system("pause>nul");
                break;


            case 3:

                repite = false;
                break;

        }

    }while (repite);
}

void  menu_resta(){
    bool repite = true;
    int opcion;
    int a, b;
    float c, d;

    do{
        system("cls");
        frame();
        // El titulo
        gotoxy(30,1);
        cout<<"MENU RESTA";
        //Opciones
        gotoxy(5,6);
        cout<<"1. Restar enteros";
        gotoxy(5,7);
        cout<<"2. Restar flotantes";
        gotoxy(5,8);
        cout<<"3. Regresar";

        //Leer la respuesta
            gotoxy(5,10);
            cout<<"Opcion: ";
            cin >> opcion;
            cout<<"\n";

        //Alternativas
        system("cls");
        frame();
        switch(opcion){
            case 1:
                gotoxy(30,1);
                cout<<"MENU RESTA";
                gotoxy(5,6);
                cout<<"numero 1: ";
                cin >> a;
                gotoxy(5,7);
                cout<<"numero 2: ";
                cin >> b;
                gotoxy(5,9);
                cout << a <<" - " << b <<" = " <<a - b << endl;
                system("pause>nul");
                break;

            case 2:
                gotoxy(30,1);
                cout<<"MENU RESTA";
                gotoxy(5,6);
                cout<<"numero 1: ";
                cin >> c;
                gotoxy(5,7);
                cout<<"numero 2: ";
                cin >> d;
                gotoxy(5,9);
                cout << c <<" - " << d <<" = " <<c - d << endl;
                system("pause>nul");
                break;


            case 3:
                repite = false;
                break;

        }

    }while (repite);
}

void  menu_multiplicacion(){
    bool repite = true;
    int opcion;
    int a, b;
    float c, d;

    do{
        system("cls");
        frame();
        // El titulo
        gotoxy(30,1);
        cout<<"MENU MULTIPLICACION";
        //Opciones
        gotoxy(5,6);
        cout<<"1. Multiplicar enteros";
        gotoxy(5,7);
        cout<<"2. Multiplicar flotantes";
        gotoxy(5,8);
        cout<<"3. Regresar\n";

        //Leer la respuesta
        gotoxy(5,10);
            cout<<"Opcion: ";
            cin >> opcion;
            cout<<"\n";

        //Alternativas
        system("cls");
        frame();
        switch(opcion){
            case 1:
                gotoxy(30,1);
                cout<<"MENU MULTIPLICACION";
                gotoxy(5,6);
                cout<<"numero 1: ";
                cin >> a;
                gotoxy(5,7);
                cout<<"numero 2: ";
                cin >> b;
                gotoxy(5,9);
                cout << a <<" * " << b <<" = " <<a * b << endl;
                system("pause>nul");
                break;

            case 2:
                gotoxy(30,1);
                cout<<"MENU MULTIPLICACION";
                gotoxy(5,6);
                cout<<"numero 1: ";
                cin >> c;
                gotoxy(5,7);
                cout<<"numero 2: ";
                cin >> d;
                gotoxy(5,9);
                cout << c <<" x " << d <<" = " <<c * d << endl;
                system("pause>nul");
                break;


            case 3:
                repite = false;
                break;

        }

    }while (repite);
}

void  menu_dividir(){
    bool repite = true;
    int opcion;
    int a, b;
    float c, d;

    do{
        system("cls");
        frame();
        // El titulo
        gotoxy(30,1);
        cout<<"MENU DIVIDIR";
        //Opciones
        gotoxy(5,6);
        cout<<"1. Dividir enteros";
        gotoxy(5,7);
        cout<<"2. Dividir flotantes";
        gotoxy(5,8);
        cout<<"3. Regresar";

        //Leer la respuesta
            gotoxy(5,9);
            cout<<"Opcion: ";
            cin >> opcion;
            cout<<"\n";

        //Alternativas
        system("cls");
        frame();
        switch(opcion){
            case 1:
                gotoxy(30,1);
                cout<<"MENU DIVIDIR";
                gotoxy(5,6);
                cout<<"numero 1: ";
                cin >> a;
                gotoxy(5,7);
                cout<<"numero 2: ";
                cin >> b;

                if(b == 0){
                    gotoxy(5,9);
                    cout <<"No se puede dividir por cero"<< endl;
                }else{
                    gotoxy(5,9);
                    cout << a <<" / " << b <<" = " <<a / b << endl;
                    system("pause>nul");
                }


                break;

            case 2:
                gotoxy(30,1);
                cout<<"MENU DIVIDIR";
                gotoxy(5,6);
                cout<<"numero 1: ";
                cin >> c;
                gotoxy(5,7);
                cout<<"numero 2: ";
                cin >> d;

                if(b == 0){
                    gotoxy(5,9);        
                    cout <<"No se puede dividir por cero"<< endl;
                }else{
                    gotoxy(5,9);
                    cout << c <<" / " << d <<" = " <<a / b << endl;
                    system("pause>nul");
                }

                system("pause>nul");
                break;


            case 3:
                repite = false;
                break;

        }

    }while (repite);

}
```